# i am currently have an MYSQL syntax error

Tags: php, mysql

i am very new at MYSQL and after i created this script to update a row in the table of a MYSQL Database and run it i get this error

> Error: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '265'', Employer_VAT_number = ''45698'', Employer_Name = ''Namtax_Ltd'', Employer' at line 3

here is the code

```
// username and password sent from form 
    $Numb=$_POST["Numb"]; 
    $VAT=$_POST["VAT"];
    $Name=$_POST["Name"]; 
    $Addr=$_POST["Addr"]; 
    $PO=$_POST["PO"];  

    // To protect MySQL injection (more detail about MySQL injection )
    $Numb =  stripslashes($Numb);
    $VAT =   stripslashes($VAT) ;
    $Name = stripslashes($Name) ;
    $Addr =  stripslashes($Addr) ;
    $PO =   stripslashes($PO) ;
    $Numb = "'" . mysql_real_escape_string($Numb) . "'";
    $VAT = "'" . mysql_real_escape_string($VAT) .  "'";
    $Name =  "'" . mysql_real_escape_string($Name) .  "'";
    $Addr = "'" . mysql_real_escape_string($Addr) . "'";
    $PO = "'" . mysql_real_escape_string($PO) . "'";

    $sql=("UPDATE $tb1_name SET Employer_Registration_Number ='".$Numb."', Employer_VAT_number = '".$VAT."', Employer_Name = '".$Name."', Employer_Address = '".$Addr."', Employer_Postal_Address = '".$PO."' WHERE Employer_Name = '".$Name."' ");

    if (!mysqli_query($con,$sql))
      {
      die('Error: ' . mysqli_error($con));
      }
    echo "Successfully Updated";

    mysqli_close($con);
    ?>
    </body>
```

Comment: You also have a gigantic SQL Injection vulnerability. Anyway, echo out $Numb for example and you'll figure it out on your own after that.

Comment: well, you're surrounding with quotes your pieces of data 2 times : when you escape them and then in your final request. Do one or the other but not both :)

Comment: *"// To protect MySQL injection (more detail about MySQL injection )"* - Use prepared statements and do away with all those additional functions.

Comment: `stripslashes` is useless for escaping and shouldn't be in your code in the first place.

Answer (score 3):

This here:

```
$Numb = "'" . mysql_real_escape_string($Numb) . "'";
```

*Firstly,* that isn't proper syntax and you're using `mysqli_` to connect with, *least I sure hope you are*.

- Those different MySQL APIs do **not** intermix with each other.

That should read as:

```
$Numb = mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$Numb);
```

while doing the same for the rest of your variables, following the same method outlined here.

---

**Footnotes:**

Seeing you didn't post what `$tb1_name` is, doubt that would be causing an issue. But just for the sake of argument, wrap that variable in ticks, just so if your table name changes to something containing a hyphen or a space, or anything that MySQL will complain about.

```
UPDATE `$tb1_name` SET...
```

Plus, since you didn't mention which MySQL API you're using to connect with, make sure it is in fact `mysqli_` and not `mysql_` or PDO.

It doesn't look like it, but I have to be 100% sure.

**Your connection should resemble something like this:**

```
$con = mysqli_connect("yourhost","user","pass","your_DB") 
or die("Error " . mysqli_error($con));
```

Again, those different MySQL APIs do **not** intermix with each other.

- Consult (PHP: Choosing an API - Manual): https://php.net/mysqlinfo.api.choosing

---

> *"I am very new at MYSQL..."*

Seeing you're new to this:

- Use [**`mysqli` with prepared statements**](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php), or [**PDO with prepared statements**](http://php.net/pdo.prepared-statements).

---

**Additional notes.** (as an edit)

I noticed another question you posted earlier:

- https://stackoverflow.com/q/30191388/

where you said *"Thank you it worked "* in the answer given https://stackoverflow.com/a/30191647/

**I don't get that.**

How could that possibly work where you're using `if (!mysqli_query($con,$sql))`?

- You'll need to show us the way you're connecting with here.

If you truly want to see if your query was successful, use [`mysqli_affected_rows()`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.affected-rows.php).

```
if(mysqli_affected_rows($con)){
   echo "Successfully updated.";
   }

else{
   echo "Not updated.";
}
```

---

Add [**error reporting**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php) to the top of your file(s) which will help find errors.

```
<?php 
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);

// rest of your code
```

**Sidenote:** Error reporting should only be done in staging, and never production.

Comment: *"Give a man a fish, and you feed him for a day; show him how to catch fish, and you feed him for a lifetime."*